# How to integrate zuul-ci with gitlab?

Tags: zuul-ci

i'm newbe in zuul-ci.
I am installing and configuring zuul-ci according to the document below.

- https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/latest/tutorials/quick-start.html

However, the documentation is not integrated with gitlab and it is difficult to configure properly. Is there anyone who has integrated zuul-ci and gitlab to install and configure it?